# Fetch value of array object using get() in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting value of `doc.data()` using `get()`.

Console.log(doc.data()) reads:

```
{ 'abc': 
   [ { fullname: 'samar chadha',
       number: 1,
       authid: '8SlzKpqVdXWGQ4dk7zVP23Uh0Pr2' } ] }
```

I need to fetch the value of **number** in a variable.

When I try like this `doc.data().abc[0].number` it gives error.

How do I fetch this value in a variable ?

This is how it looks in console [here abc is 9-JUN-2020]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
const abc = "9-JUN-2020";
const numberVar = doc.data()[abc][0].number;
```

It uses the [square brackets notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)